# Matplotlib fill between functionality

Tags: python, matplotlib

I saw the use of fill_between in in one the sentdex tutorial on matplotlib.
The code was like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

axis=plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0)) #a and b are lists of equal sizes
axis.plot(a,b)
axis.fill_between(a,b,34,where=(b>34),facecolor='r',alpha=.5)
```

Now his code ran fine and what he got in output was colored face on the portion where values in b were larger than 34.
But the same gives error for me :

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

I cant find how to use the where functionality

Comment: `But the same gives error for me : TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'` when you do what different writing what other code, which throws this error then?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. In any case the tutorial may have been using `numpy` arrays which will not give this error

Comment: DavidG seems to have hit it correctly.
The code of the OP has a comment (#a and b are lists...)

If b is truly a list an not an numpy array, the the error is telling you exactly the problem: not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'.

Comment: sorry for my mistake. It was a numpy array and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm following same tutorial and I had same problem. You need to import numpy library and then convert your list to numpy array and then everything will work perfectly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

b = numpy.array(b)

axis=plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0)) #a and b are lists of equal sizes
axis.plot(a,b)
axis.fill_between(a,b,34,where=(b>34),facecolor='r',alpha=.5)
```